# Smooth radial gradient

Tags: java, algorithm, gradient, radial

So, I'm trying to create a radial gradient (for static lighting in a game). I came up with this:

```
int step = 4;
int forLen = (radius / step);
g.setColor(new Color(0, 0, 0, intensity));
for (int i = 0; i < forLen; i++)
    g.fillOval(radius - i * step, radius - i * step, i * step * 2, i * step * 2);
```

But the result i get is this:

[image]

I'd like to get a smoother gradient, like:

[image]

I tried playing around with the step and the intensity, but i can't get something similar to the gradient above.
What would be a good way of doing this??
Thanks in advance!

Comment: No need to include tags in the title. Removed ;)

Comment: Could the problem be that you are drawing each new circle on top of an older one, thus causing the alpha to "stack" and increase much faster?

Comment: At second glance, that seems to be what you're actually trying to accomplish since you're working with a constant alpha, nvm...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have a concrete answer, but the look of the second picture left me the impression that the intensity is not decreasing linearly, but rather exponentially.

Could you try instead of doing a linear decreasing function, use a exponential function instead? For every step outwards, multiply the intensity with a fixed number `a` < 1.

Comment: Maybe not exactly exponentially, but most likely superlinearly.

Comment: Thanks! ...i took your answer and decide to use it, but in the opposite way. I started from the outer circle, going inwards. With a really low starting intensity (0.01 for example) i multiplied it with a fixed number > 1 (1.02 for example), and that gave me the exact result i wanted, and a lot more control!

Comment: @Sylar Great I could help, the way you are using is quite interesting:)